# Lion Hunter Achievement Minecraft 1.14.3 (current Xbox One release) Cannot Feed Ocelot

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a big problem, ocelots don't come to me while I hold any raw fish while I crouch or stand. They aren't scared, they don't scurrying away from me. When I hold the raw fish sometimes the ocelot will stand still, look at me for a few seconds then walk off. I can't feed them or anything, but I noticed they still had a hit box as I couldn't eat while trying to feed them. I tried reloading my save and then the game all together, nothing. I also tried restarting my Xbox to no avail. I'm trying for the 'Lion Hunter Achievement' on Xbox one 1.14.3, is there anything I need to know, is this a bug or intended as I can't get my achievement. Seems really weird, like a bug. Also cakes won't work and I just get buckets back lol.

Answer (score -1):

Prehaps it's a broken achievement as since the Village and Pillage update you can't properly tame ocelots, as tamable cats are now a thing in villages. The fact that the achievement is still existing might be an oversight.

Comment: BlueTangsRock, I think it's possible that it's an oversight. I know that I cannot tame the ocelot due to the update but the achievement states "Gain the trust of an Ocelot." This suggests to me that the achievement is still intentionally in the game as it's seems as though 'trust' and 'tame' are two different things. I wonder if damaging the ocelot then trying to feed/heal it would work. Like when you heal a tamed wolf,cat,horse. Going to mess around and see what I can find.

Comment: Oh dang, that's right I forgot that you can now gain an ocelot's "trust", either by a similar to the original taming method or to how it is with foxes I believe. It's definitely not the same as taming, though as it pretty much only makes ocelots not run away from the player anymore.